# Return only text before last underscore in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript

If I have a string like so:

```
var str = 'Arthropoda_Arachnida_Zodariidae_Habronestes_hunti';
```

How can I get just the first part of the string before the last underscore?

In this case I want just `'Arthropoda_Arachnida_Zodariidae_Habronestes'`

Comment: You can use a `RegExp` `"Arthropoda_Arachnida_Zodariidae_Habronestes_hunti".replace(/(.*)_.*$/g, "$1")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Slice and lastIndexOf:

```
str.slice(0, str.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

Comment: Beat me by 26 seconds

Comment: yep! :D you are the winner! :D
Fell free to upvote, since i don't wan't to be in -1 ;) I will accept this answer in 8 minuts

Comment: Ha James. That always happens to me. Type up a long answer and someone has already answered before me. :)

Comment: This doesn't include the last character before the underscore (the "s")

Comment: Not sure how you got that Cos. It does for me both in the browser and in Node.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using `split` method:

```
var s2= 'Arthropoda_Arachnida_Zodariidae_Habronestes_hunti';
var s1= s2.substr(0, s2.lastIndexOf('_'));
```

or:

```
var str = 'Arthropoda_Arachnida_Zodariidae_Habronestes_hunti';
str.split('_',4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) should give you what you want.

```
var str = "Arthropoda_Arachnida_Zodariidae_Habronestes_hunti";
var start = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexof("_"));
// -> "Arthropoda_Arachnida_Zodariidae_Habronestes"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this also

```
var str = "Arthropoda_Arachnida_Zodariidae_Habronestes_hunti";
alert(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_")+1)) //to get Last word

alert(str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("_")))  //to get first part
```