# How to get substring from string after last seen to specific characer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I want to get substring from string at last index match space and put it into another string :

for example 
if I have : `var string1="hello any body from me";`

in string1 I have 4 spaces and I want to get the word after last spaces in string1 so here I want to get the word "me" ... 
I don't know number of spaces in string1 ... so How I can get substring from string after last seen to specific characer like space ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return only text before last underscore in JavaScript string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208101/return-only-text-before-last-underscore-in-javascript-string)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this using the `split` method, where `input` is your string:

```
var splitted = input.split(' ');
var s = splitted[splitted.length-1];
```

```js
var splitted = "hello any body from me".split(' ');
var s = splitted[splitted.length-1];
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` to make it an array and get the last element:

```
var arr = st.split(" "); // where string1 is st
var result = arr[arr.length-1];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split the string by a given separator, " " in this case, and then get the final substring of the returned array.

**This is a good method if you want to use other parts of the string and it is also easily readable:**

```js
// setup your string
var string1 = "hello any body from me";

// split your string into an array of substrings with the " " separator
var splitString = string1.split(" ");

// get the last substring from the array
var lastSubstr = splitString[splitString.length - 1];

// this will log "me"
console.log(lastSubstr);

// ...

// oh i now actually also need the first part of the string
// i still have my splitString variable so i can use this again!

// this will log "hello"
console.log(splitString[0]);
```

**This is a good method without the need for the rest of the substrings if you prefer to write quick and dirty:**

```js
// setup your string
var string1 = "hello any body from me";

// split your string into an array of substrings with the " " separator, reverse it, and then select the first substring
var lastSubstr = string1.split(" ").reverse()[0];

// this will log "me"
console.log(lastSubstr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just :

```
var string1 = "hello any body from me";
var result = string1.split(" ").reverse()[0];
console.log(result); // me
```

Thank's to reverse method

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regular expression to avoid the array overhead:

```js
var string1 = "hello any body from me";
var matches = /\s(\S*)$/.exec(string1);
if (matches)
    console.log(matches[1]);
```